# JFreeChart - how to reverse axis order

Tags: axis, jfreechart, reverse

I'm creating XYPlot and I need to reverse the order on y-Axis (that is, I need lower numbers to be higher on the axis). I would appreciate any hints how to do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem as you. I found this:

```
ChartPanel.getChart().getXYPlot().getRangeAxis().setInverted(boolean)
```

Comment: I found it:

`if(CP.getChart().getXYPlot().getDomainAxis().isInverted()) {
                            CP.getChart().getXYPlot().getDomainAxis().setInverted(false);
                        } else {
                            CP.getChart().getXYPlot().getDomainAxis().setInverted(true);
                        }`

Answer (score 1):

to reverse the Y-axis ... you can use

```
ChartPanel.getChart().getXYPlot().getDomainAxis().setInverted(boolean)
```

Source:
[Reverse X-axis numeric labels in JFreeChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442039/reverse-x-axis-numeric-labels-in-jfreechart)